# Efficient solution to compare two large arrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, simplexml

I like to compare two arrays without using `in_array` as both of these arrays are extremely large (50,000 plus). I like to generate a new array of all the ones that are missing from the first array.

What would be the fastest most efficient solution I would use?

**First Array**
Multidimensional array generated from SQL Query

```
Array (
  [0] => Array (
    [id] => 17228219
    [name] => ...
  )
  [1] => Array (
    [id] => 17228220
    [name] => ...
  )
  [2] => Array (
    [id] => 17228221
    [name] => ...
  )
  [3] => Array (
    [id] => 17228222
    [name] => ...
  )
  [4] => Array (
    [id] => 17228223
    [name] => ...
  )
  [5] => Array (
    [id] => 17228224
    [name] => ...
  )
)
```

**Second Array**
Generated from Simple XML

```
Array (
  [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object (
    [0] => 17228219
  )
  [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object (
    [0] => 17228221
  )
  [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object (
    [0] => 17228222
  )
  [3] => SimpleXMLElement Object (
    [0] => 17228224
  )
)
```

**New Array**
Create an array with missing IDs

```
Array (
  [0] => Array (
    [id] => 17228220
    [name] => ...
  )
  [1] => Array (
    [id] => 17228223
    [name] => ...
  )
)
```

Comment: didya try `array_diff`?

Comment: the first one is from a db, use a query to compare to the 2nd rather than reading it all in to memory

Comment: Assuming those id fields are unique in each array, i'd suggest building a new array that's keyed `id => name`. then a simple array_diff will do all the heavy lifting.

Comment: I did try the array_diff - takes a long time. Yes it works, was hoping for a faster solution without so much server load.

Answer (score 2):

you can make it a little faster by implementing an AVL Tree for example, then it will do it in 
O(N*Log(N)), you can find [many implementations of trees in php](http://phptouch.com/2011/04/17/implementation-of-a-tree-structure-in-php/)

that will be a little faster then the double 'for' (N^2),
also, you can sort the arrays and move every iteration one step on both arrays, this way you can find the difference, but this is also O(N*Log(N)), its hard to believe it can be faster than this.

p.s.
if its already sorted (like in the code you posted), then you can do it in O(N) with the second way

Comment: Reading up on this right now and yes that is the structure. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From the algorithm-point of view the fastest would be item-wise (mergesort like) compare and complement detection by one pass with two sorted arrays... with time complexity O(N logN) +  O(MlogM) + O(M + N) ~ 
O(N log N)...

AVL Tree is an overkill...

Comment: avl tree is almost the same as a sort.... but as i said, if its already sorted then it can be done in linear time

Comment: I'm not sure if there is some support for AVL trees, but sorting is available for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Using the 'id' as the array key for both sets would make for a much faster PHP based algorithm as V-X suggests.

However, the most efficient solution is to leave your reference set in the database and add the XML records to it, detecting collisions / non-collisions either on insert or on a subsequent SELECT with join, particularly if the reference set is larger than the comparison set.

You don't say what you intend doing with the un-matched data - which has some bearing on the approach.

Comment: I have to delete database records as well files on server itself.